# How can I put all the results of 2 spiders in one XML with scrapy?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, scrapy

I made 2 spiders with Scrapy and I need to put it together in one script and put all the results in one XML.

Here are some ways to manage 2 spiders in one, but I'm not able to put the results together in one XML.

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

Is there any way to launch 1 script with 2 spiders and collect all the results in one file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scrapy project create a python script named script.py add the 
following lines of code.Assuming name of the spider files are spider_one.py and spider_two.py and your spiders are SpiderOne and SpiderTwo respectively.
So in you script.py add.

```
from spiders.spider_one import SpiderOne
from spiders.spider_two import SpiderTwo

# scrapy api
from scrapy import signals, log
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.settings import Settings


file = "your_file.json" #your results
TO_CRAWL = [SpiderOne,SpiderTwo]


# list of crawlers that are running 
RUNNING_CRAWLERS = []

def spider_closing(spider):
    """Activates on spider closed signal"""
    log.msg("Spider closed: %s" % spider, level=log.INFO)
    RUNNING_CRAWLERS.remove(spider)
    if not RUNNING_CRAWLERS:
        reactor.stop()

log.start(loglevel=log.DEBUG)
for spider in TO_CRAWL:
    settings = Settings()
    settings.set("USER_AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36")
    settings.set("FEED_FORMAT",'json')
    settings.set("FEED_URI",file)
    # settings.set("ITEM_PIPELINES",{ 'pipelines.CustomPipeline': 300})
    settings.set("DOWNLOAD_DELAY",1)
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler_obj = spider()
    RUNNING_CRAWLERS.append(crawler_obj)

    # stop reactor when spider closes
    crawler.signals.connect(spider_closing, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(crawler_obj)
    crawler.start()

# blocks process so always keep as the last statement
reactor.run()
```

The example works with json but can be suitably adapted to xml too.

Comment: I had tested this code but it throws me an ImportError when I'm trying to import my items in each spider.

Comment: @3mpty88 Can you please post the error logs?Have you ensured that the spiders are in the **spiders** folder?

Comment: ImportError: No module named myproject.items is the error that I get from that code. The spiders are in the spiders folder.

Comment: I've solved the import error. Now I have another one:
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'update_settings'
It's my first time with python & scrapy so I don't have much experience.

Comment: @3mpty Run **python your_script.py** which has all the configuration stated above. **scrapy crawl your_spider** won't work here because it is looking for the the settings.py file.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though - there's no merging (reducing) of results from the spiders (into one XML)...